# Vue cannot read property of null while using v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component

**Is there a way to solve an error which says id not defined on v-bind:key="persons.id" ?**

My View

```
<div v-for="reservation in reservationNameByTime" v-bind:key="reservation.id">
  {{reservation.id}} /** displays 1 **/
  <div v-for="player in reservation.Players" v-bind:key="player.id">
    {{player.id}} /**displays 1 **/
    <div v-for="persons in player.Person" v-bind:key="persons.id"> /** throws an error as id of null **/
      {{persons.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSON DATA

```
reservationNameByTime: [
 {
  id: 1,  /** defines reservation id **/
  Players: [
    id: 1,  /** defines players id **/
    Person:{
      id: 1,  /** defines the person id **/
      name: John
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

Image for array data

[image: JSON array data]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div v-for="(reservation, i) in reservationNameByTime" v-bind:key="i">
    {{reservation.id}} /** displays 1 **/
    <div v-for="(player, j) in reservation.Players" v-bind:key="j">
        {{player.id}} /**displays 1 **/
        <div v-for="(persons, k) in player.Person" v-bind:key="k">
            {{persons.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`player.Person` is an object and [`v-for` on an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) iterates through the properties of the object and returns its values. In this case it would be `1` and `John`. So you're trying to get `1.id` and `John.id`.

If you're only going to have one person, you could just do:

```
div v-bind:key="player.Person.id">
   {{player.Person.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: what if I have multiple names?

Comment: In what structure?

Comment: Players[0] consists the same data above such as Person[{id:1, name:John}] and Players[1] follows the same pattern and consists of Person[{id:2, name: Dave}] .

Comment: But currently you have Person{id:1, name:John}. Have you tried putting it in an array?

Comment: Person can not be an array, this is not logic, use players or persons but not both, see below an other implementation

Comment: @DelenaMalan I just edited my question. There is an image description of my array data.

Comment: My solution should work for your data. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is malformed, try this with the html code in your post

```
reservationNameByTime: [{
    id: 1,
    Players: [{
        id: 1,
        Person: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'John'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Marc'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

But this (below) is better, for each reservation, you have an id and a list of players, player have id and name

```
reservation: [{
    id: 1,
    players: [{
        id: 21,
        name: 'John'
    },
    {
        id: 55,
        name: 'Marc'
    }]
},
{
    id: 2,
    players: [{
        id: 34,
        name: 'Adrien'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: 'Marion'
    }]
}]
```

HTML / VUE

```
<div v-for="reservation in reservations" v-bind:key="reservation.id">
    {{reservation.id}}
    <div v-for="player in reservation.players" v-bind:key="player.id">
        {{player}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just updated my question. Now we can view image description of how array data is formatted for players.

Comment: If you really want to use this array try this `<div v-for="el in player" v-bind:key="player.Person.id"> 
      {{el.name}}
    </div>`